# What is difference between ARFCN , UARFCN and EARFCN?

Tags: android, gsm, telephonymanager

In android API , depends on which generation mobile connects to , provide ARFCN , UARFCN and EARFCN . What is difference between them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ARFCN - absolute radio-frequency channel number. Identifies two separate radio carriers, one for uplink and one for downlink in GSM frequencies.

UARFCN - UTRA Absolute Radio Frequency Channel Number. Identifies the uplink and downlink in UMTS frequencies. Its simply a unique number form which the uplink and downlink frequencies can be calculated.

EARFCN - EUTRA Absolute radio-frequency channel number. Identifies the uplink and downlink in LTE frequencies

Comment: In android 6 I can not access ARFCN/UARFCN/EARFCN of cellular connection. Methods of getting these parameters are not part of Android API level 23 . There exist another way in android 6 to get these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

ARFCN stands for absolute radio frequency channel number. Networking technologies utilise ranges of frequencies named bands.

For mobile networking technologies, these are integers used to represent a specific frequency within a band which a device and network use to communicate over.

The character(s) before ARFCN denote which technology is being referenced.

- ARFCNs are used for 2G/GSM services
- UARFCNs are used for UTRA (3G/WCDMA)
- EARFCNs are used for EUTRA (4G/LTE)
- NARFCNs are used for NR (5G)

The ARFCN represents the centre of the frequency band currently in use. You can use this centre frequency alongside the bandwidth value to calculate the full channel in use.

It's worth remembering that, for Android APIs, we rely on the device and chipset vendor correctly providing this data to the system. Some devices will incorrectly report the NR signalling channel ARFCN (SSB-ARFCN) as the NARFCN. The SSB-ARFCN does not always represent the centre of the NR band being used.

Answer (score 0):

They all mean thesame thing for different technologies. 2G - ARFCN, 3G - UARFCN, 4G EARFCN, 5G - ARFCN

It is the center frequency of the channel being used for transmission on the DL or UL